# Функция при нажатии jquery

Tags: html, css, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при повторном нажатии на 1 таб стили не меняются?
При нажатии на другие табы все нормально.

```js
$(".no_active_tab").click(function() {
  $(".active_tab").removeClass("active_tab").addClass("no_active_tab");
  $(this).removeClass("no_active_tab").addClass("active_tab");

});
```

```css
.tabs_name .no_active_tab {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f6f8fa;
}

.tabs_name .active_tab {
  background: #fff;
  color: inherit;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="card" class="tabs">
  <div class="tabs_name">
    <div data-open="are_settings" class="active_tab">
      1
    </div>
    <div data-open="shop_settings" class="no_active_tab">
      2
    </div>
    <div data-open="account_settings" class="no_active_tab">
      3
    </div>
    <div data-open="tarif_settings" class="no_active_tab">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что когда Вы вешаете обработчики событий на клик при загрузке страницы, у первого элемента нет класса `no_active_tab` тем самым вешаются события на те элементы у которых первоначально был данный класс. поэтому после того как на первый элемент добавляется данный класс ничего не происходит. Добавьте общий класс `tabs-item` например на все элементы и на него вешаете событие и будет Вам счастье

```js
$(".tabs-item").click(function() {
  $(".active_tab").removeClass("active_tab").addClass("no_active_tab");
  $(this).removeClass("no_active_tab").addClass("active_tab");

});
```

```css
.tabs_name .no_active_tab {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f6f8fa;
}

.tabs_name .active_tab {
  background: #fff;
  color: inherit;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="card" class="tabs">
  <div class="tabs_name">
    <div data-open="are_settings" class="active_tab tabs-item">
      1
    </div>
    <div data-open="shop_settings" class="no_active_tab tabs-item">
      2
    </div>
    <div data-open="account_settings" class="no_active_tab tabs-item">
      3
    </div>
    <div data-open="tarif_settings" class="no_active_tab tabs-item">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин пожалуйста!